# Filter NSArray with NSPredicate inexact/similar match?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray, nspredicate

I have an NSArray of 5 NSArrays that each contain NSDictionaries. The dictionaries contain only strings. I'm trying to use NSPredicate to filter out particular dictionaries, however it only seems to work with an exact match. I would like for it to ignore any punctuation such as `:` or `-`. Here's what I have currently.

```
NSString *seriesTitle = @" Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood - ";
NSPredicate *titlePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:
                                   @"series_title CONTAINS[cd]%@", seriesTitle];
NSArray *filtered = [arraytoEvaluate filteredArrayUsingPredicate:titlePredicate]
```

Within "arraytoEvaluate" is an NSDictionary containing this key-value pair `@"series_title" : @"Fullmetal Alchemist: Brotherhood"`. That's the one I want it to match to. My predicate does not pick this up even though I'm requesting a [cd] search, which I believe ignores punctuation/whitespace, correct?

Using `series_title LIKE[cd]%@`gives me this crash:

`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do regex matching on object`

Using `BEGINSWITH` instead gives me this:
`'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Can't do a substring operation with something that isn't a string`

If I pass in the string exactly, it will pick it up and give me the the Array that contains the dictionary that contains a match, but only if the search term is an exactly match.

Also, it will give me all of them, not an NSArray containing the single NSDictionary that contains a match. I'm not sure what to do about that. I understand that `filteredArrayUsingPredicate` is supposed to return an Array, but I will then need to iterate through that Array for the specific NSDictionary that contains a match for the search terms. That's a secondary issue however. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have two problems (a) the match is wrong and (b) you have nested arrays.

(a) `[cd]` means ignore case and diacritics, not punctuation and whitespace. A solution here is to use a regular expression and `MATCHES[CD]` as the predicate. You need a regular expression which will match the terms you are looking for. A basic re is:

```
@"fullmetal[^a-z]*alchemist[^a-z]*brotherhood"
```

where `[^a-z]*` matches zero or more (`*`) characters from the set `[...]` of every character which is not (`^`) a letter `a-z`.

While this works it probably matches far more than you wish - you should refine the regular expression.

(b) The error you got `Can't do regex matching on object...` is because you cannot match a regular expression against an array, and the elements of your array are themselves array. You can address this using a simple loop over the elements, something along the lines of:

```
NSMutableArray *filtered = [NSMutableArray new];                                          // allocate an empty mutable array in which to accumulate the matches
for(NSArray *subArray in arraytoEvaluate)                                                 // loop over each sub array
   [filtered addObjectsFromArray:[subArray filteredArrayUsingPredicate: titlePredicate]]; // and perform the predicate
```

HTH

Comment: Ok I see how this works. I only have one question though. I only used `NSString *seriesTitle = @" Fullmetal Alchemist Brotherhood - ";` as an example for this question, but in reality the search string will vary. How do I set up the regex string in that case? I could do `NSString *regex = @"[^a-z]*[^a-z]*";` but where does the input string come into play? Thanks.

Comment: @JosephToronto - You have to design an algorithm for constructing a regular expression which matches the text with the flexibility you need. E.g. If you are matching a sequence of words regardless of intervening white space or punctuation then your algorithm might be to extract the words and then join them with a pattern which matches whitespace & punctation - which is essentially what I did by hand with your example only the joining pattern is *very* general!

Comment: Do you have any documentation for nested arrays not working? > "cannot match a regular expression against an array, and the elements of your array are themselves array" <

Comment: @pkamb - The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001795-SW1) describes `CONTAINS`, `MATCHES` as "string comparisons", that is they operate on individual strings. When you use `filteredArrayUsingPredicate:` on an *array of dictionaries* the predicate is (effectively) applied using `NSPredicate`'s `evaluateWithObject:` to each dictionary in turn and key lookup on that dictionary returns a string. (cont...)

Comment: (...cont) If you do the same with an *array of arrays of dictionaries* an *array of dictionaries* is passed to `evaluateWithObject:` and key lookup on that array returns and *array of strings* - and string comparisons are not documented for arrays. As the question shows *some* of the operators give errors (`LIKE`, `MATCHES`, `BEGINSWITH`) while others (`CONTAINS`) don't error but appear to work differently in an *undocumented* way. Stick with what is documented. HTH